# While importing pyplot from matplotlib it hangs

Tags: macos, python-2.7, matplotlib, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to import pyplot but my python code will not run and gets stuck at the following spot:

`from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 24, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 29, in <module>
    import matplotlib.collections as collections
  File "matplotlib/collections.py", line 23, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
  File "matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 50, in <module>
    import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
  File "matplotlib/textpath.py", line 11, in <module>
    import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
  File "matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1356, in <module>
    _rebuild()
  File "matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1341, in _rebuild
    fontManager = FontManager()
  File "matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 989, in __init__
    self.ttffiles = findSystemFonts(paths) + findSystemFonts()
  File "matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 318, in findSystemFonts
    for f in get_fontconfig_fonts(fontext):
  File "matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 275, in get_fontconfig_fonts
    output = pipe.communicate()[0]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 791, in communicate
    stdout = _eintr_retry_call(self.stdout.read)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 476, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)
```

I have tried uninstalling matplotlib using pip so that I can reinstall the package but that also throws a lengthy list of errors.  I am running this on my Mac OSX 10.11.

Comment: When you say it gets stuck, do you mean it throws an exception, or hangs?

Comment: How did you install python and matplotlib in the first place?

Comment: i installed matplotlib using pip.

Comment: I wonder if you're being affected by this bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue13817

Comment: just give it some time, don't abort it--subsequent import calls to matplotlib work without any delays

Comment: Did you find a solution? Experiencing the same problem...

Comment: @CentAu no i never found a solution.  ended up just running on my raspberry pi

Answer (score 2):

Better use Conda. 
I had this problem too [in windows]. I uninstalled and reinstalled python completely. Then, it was perfect. I think, it is because of corrupt files. Still, I moved to conda environment. It is more smooth and comfortable.

1. Download Anaconda from Scipy page
2. Open Conda command prompt
3. Use the code: `-conda install pymc pymc`
4. This code installs Conda environment, Scipy, Pymc, Numpy, matplotlib and setup tools
5. If you want only matplotlib, you can use pip install matplotlib.

It works good for me.

If you want to re-work on existing framework, better uninstall python setup and reinstall. Then try pip install. It works smoothly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` hanging on a remote Linux machined due to having X11 forwarding setup on the remote (client), but forgetting to start the X11 server locally. On Windows, I started XMing and was able to proceed.